# Enable tab completion for Statistics Toolbox

Tags: matlab

Example: If I write plotR in command window and hit Tab I get "No Completions Found". Statistics Toolbox has a function called plotResiduals which should pop up. How do I enable tab completion for the Statistics Toolbox?

Comment: The Matlab documentation and website will be of way more help to you on topics such as this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`plotResiduals` is not a function, but a method in the class `LinearModel`. So when you have an object `x` of that class and you type `x.plotR` and then hit Tab, the completion occurs (without pop-up, because there's only one possibility).